# The correct syntax to divide two numbers in a PHP Select Statement

Tags: php, select, operators

I am trying to order the results of my select statement by 2 calculations already within the statement if that makes sense..

```
$sql = "SELECT Make, Model,COUNT(*) as total ,SUM(FrontGross) as sumGross FROM table GROUP BY Model ORDER BY (sumGross/total) DESC LIMIT 20";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        }
    }
```

It does not work with the ORDER BY (sumGross/total). What is the correct syntax to use to divide sumGross by total?

Comment: Show your sample data and expected result set

Comment: How do you do *what* correctly, exactly?  It's not really clear to me what the problem is.  You order results of a query with an `ORDER BY` clause, in what way is this not working?

Comment: I am just looking to get correct syntax in the select statement, not so much worried with the output.

Comment: You may have to add a computed column `sumGross / total as SumGrossByTotal` into your `SELECT` clause and then use the column alias `SumGrossByTotal` in your `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  Make, 
  Model,
  COUNT(*) as total,
  SUM(FrontGross) as sumGross,
  SUM(FrontGross)/COUNT(*) as win 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Model 
ORDER BY win ASC 
LIMIT 20";
```